# Obtaining last revisions in Couchbase with N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Suppose I have a bucket of documents in Couchbase like below.

```
user lastUpdate    otherField1
a    "2015-12-06"  1    
a    "2015-11-06"  2
b    "2015-12-05"  3    
b    "2015-10-05"  4
```

How could I obtain in a single N1QL query the last updated document for each user ?
I've started using N1QL a few days ago and I don't know how to do such complex queries. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT user, MAX( [ lastUpdate, doc ] ) AS pair
FROM my_bucket AS doc
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: That's very elegant thank you. But I don't know how I would have found this alone. Do you have any pointer to the relevant documentation ?

Comment: I have added a JIRA ticket to document this: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/DOC-982

Comment: Thank you I hope to be able to do some magic like you one day! In the meantime it's practical to know that someone with the knowledge on n1ql is ready to help. I've been using mongo for one year and I've switched to couchbase during the weekend, I really like it.

Comment: In fact you don't just have knowledge, you're the man! Congratulations for what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you :) I do like this particular query. When you've used Couchbase and N1QL a bit, please share your experience and use case with us on the Couchbase forums.

Comment: The query above doesn't work @geraldss, the documents by user are not the latest ones. The query I use (adapted to the example) is SELECT *, MAX( [ lastUpdate, doc ] ) AS pair FROM my_bucket AS doc GROUP BY user;

Comment: This query works to get the whole document SELECT MAX( [ lastUpdate, doc ] )[1] FROM my_bucket AS doc GROUP BY user

Comment: For info, I really liked this paper on sql++ http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3631 to get more intuition about how an N1QL request works.

Comment: how would you get the last n record per user ? It's more out of curiosity as your answer already taught me many things.

Comment: We work closely with the SQL++ team at UCSD. Not sure why you would do SELECT *. We will disable SELECT * when there is a GROUP BY.

Comment: BTW, your second query is correct. I wanted to provide a template to show why it is picking up the latest, so I left lastUpdate in there. Let me think about last N per user...

Comment: Because I wanted to select all fields of a document. Yes I've read about n1ql = sql++.

Comment: Now I understand better how an n1ql must work. It must be some kind of map reduce in order to be able to do a max operation on arrays created on the fly.

Comment: N1QL is actually based on SQL, not map-reduce. SQL predates map-reduce, and always had aggregation (GROUP BY). Map-reduce is a form of aggregation / reduction. There is overlap between the capabilities of SQL / N1QL aggregation on the one had, and map-reduce on the other hand.